# JQuery cannot read property part of a JSON

Tags: jquery, json, reactjs

I have a React component which loads a JSON from the backend and presents them in a tabular format.

```
var App = React.createClass({

  loadMoviesFromServer: function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:9000/movies"
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      self.setState({movies: data._embedded.movies});
    });
  },

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {movies: []};
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadMoviesFromServer();
  },

  render() {
    return ( <MovieTable movies={this.state.movies}/> );
  }
});


    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root') );
    </script>
```

Below is the REST API Response :

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Sholay","day":"Monday","description":"Action"},{"id":2,"name":"Tomb Raider","day":"Monday","description":"Action"},{"id":3,"name":"Toby Maguire","day":"Tuesday","description":"Action"}]
```

However I get the error :

```
Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'movies' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'movies' of undefined
    at Object.eval (eval at transform.run (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js:4:28099), <anonymous>:97:46)
```

Should I reformat the JSON ? Or should I change the expected element in Jquery.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you console logging response `data`, you havent field `_embedded` here.

Try to remove `_embedded` and  `movies` key from setState call:

```
self.setState({movies: data});
```

Comment: Because `data` contain only array of films, and not contain any other properties which you like to see like: `_embedded` or `movies`.